# Azure data factory tempdb usage in data flow

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using data flow to copy large data to sql azure database.

I recieved an error

```
 Operation on target Data flow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job 
 failed due to reason: at Sink 'xxxx': 
 shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The database 'tempdb' has 
 reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation 
 for possible resolutions.","Details":"at Sink 'xxx': 
 shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The database 'tempdb' has 
 reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation 
 for possible resolutions."}
```

To resolve, i tried creating a different schema in the data flow setting and unchecked "Use tempdb" option and provided with schema name of schema i created.

I continue to get the same error with not much information availabe about solving thise.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure SQL sink use the global temp DB to stage the data and the size of global temp DB depends on your service tier. You can either increase the size by increasing the service tier, or use a normal user table to stage the data instead of table from global temp DB by unchecking the "Use tempdb" option and publish the changes. Please note that using user table to stage data will impact the performance significantly.

Comment: I did change to user schema .. to create temp table .. but something’s are still stored in tempdb I guess , because I could see temp table created in my schema and then data factory still giving temp db error ..